# How to Redirect domain.com/something/1000

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website built on Laravel.

I have a chain of URLs:

- `example.com/something/1000`
- `example.com/abc/1000`
- `example.com/xyz/1000`

Above URLs never existed on the website but Google is somehow noticing them.

Is there a way through `.htaccess` to redirect all those kind of URLs to:

- `example.com/something/1000` to `example.com/something`
- `example.com/abc/1000` to `example.com/abc`
- `example.com/xyz/1000` to `example.com/xyz`

Many thanks!

I am expecting a `.htaccess` code.

Comment: _"I am expecting a .htaccess code."_ - and we expect you to show a bit of effort first of all, and not just show up here with that "you make for me" attitude. So if you have not even made any _attempt_ yet - then I would suggest you start with reading up on some basics, the mentioned existing question is a good source for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but Google is somehow noticing them.

If Google is actually *indexing* them then they must have existed (at least at some point) on your site. By "exists", we mean return's a "200 OK" response code.

If these URLs really do not exist and return a "404 Not Found" response then there is nothing you really need to do here as a 404 is the correct response and is enough to prevent search engines from indexing those URLs.

If these URLs have been erroneously linked to by a third party (and Google is perhaps *crawling* these URLs) then you can implement a redirect.

Something like the following using mod_rewrite at the top of the root `.htaccess` file would redirect URLs of the form `/<something>/1000` to `/<something>`, covering the 3 examples you've listed:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "/something/1000" to "/something"
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/1000$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note that this matches URLs containing a single path-segment, followed by `/1000` at the end of the URL-path. The `$1` backreference contains the captured URL-path before `/1000`.